# Format Date In Controller

Tags: laravel

I have the following form :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">        
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('date', 'Data')}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="interval">Inicial</span>            
        {{Form::text('dateini', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="interval">Final</span>            
        {{Form::text('datefim', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

How put the date in the format " d / m / Y " before the end of this check the controller?

```
public function Empenhos(Request $request)
{
    $query = DB::table('empenho as emp')
            ->select('emp.nrEmpenho as a',DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as b"))
            ->orderby('emp.nrEmpenho');

    if ($request->dateini) $query->where('emp.date', '>=', $request->dateini);
    if ($request->datefim) $query->where('emp.date', '>=', $request->dateini)
            ->where('emp.date', '<=', $request->datefim);

    $table = $query->paginate($request->perPage ? $request->perPage : 20);

    $header = ['Numero', 'Data', 'Tipo', 'Credor', 'Ficha', 'Fonte', 'Valor'];

    return view('results.planejamento.empenhos',
            ['perPage' => $request->perPage, 'title' => $this->title,
                'title2' => $this->title2[6], 'header' => $header, 'table' => $table, 'return' => 'Empenhos']);
}
```

Ps: Any questions about the code I am available to provide any information necessary !

My english is very bad , sorry, i'm brazilian and i had to look for help here.

Comment: I don't think you should break up your `select` when using `raw`. I believe it should look like this: `select(DB::raw('emp.nrEmpenho as a, DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, "%d/%m/%Y") as b'))`.

Comment: I understood, but not work--->if ($request->dateini) $query->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, '%d/%m/%Y')"), '>=', $request->dateini);....  Sorry double comment... o.O not want delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's using Carbon\Carbon as an interface of Datetime, so You can use it by binding your input:

`$dateinit = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->dateini);
    $datefim = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->datefim);`

Now You can use Carbon object like this:

`$dateinit->format('d/m/Y');`

so the complete example code be like this:

`

```
public function Empenhos(Request $request)
{
    $dateinit = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->dateini);
    $datefim = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->datefim);

    $query = DB::table('empenho as emp')
        ->select('emp.nrEmpenho as a',DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as b"))
        ->orderby('emp.nrEmpenho');

    if ($request->dateini) $query->where('emp.date', '>=', $dateinit->format('d/m/Y'));
    if ($request->datefim) $query->where('emp.date', '>=', $dateinit->format('d/m/Y'))
        ->where('emp.date', '<=', $datefim->format('d/m/Y'));

    $table = $query->paginate($request->perPage ? $request->perPage : 20);

    $header = ['Numero', 'Data', 'Tipo', 'Credor', 'Ficha', 'Fonte', 'Valor'];

    return view('results.planejamento.empenhos',
        ['perPage' => $request->perPage, 'title' => $this->title,
            'title2' => $this->title2[6], 'header' => $header, 'table' => $table, 'return' => 'Empenhos']);
```

}
`

The only question is the default format of your Database timestamp and the `date` field type.